# Preventing OutOfMemoryError on android

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory

I have recently been developing a game for android. On my Samsung S3 Neo+ with 1.5GB memory, my app, with a total of ~14MB of picture assets (PNGs). My app loads all of these PNGs into Bitmap objects which are, of course, stored in the RAM. After loading all the assets into a hashmap (`HashMap<String, Bitmap>`) where the string is the path of the resource in the assets folder and the Bitmap is loaded bitmap object. After loading another bitmap after all of these have been cached in the hashmap, I get an OutOfMemoryError and the app crashes.

Although the `Bitmap` object obviously has some overhead, I cannot see how 14MB of assets can possible overflow the VMs memory.

Is there something I am missing about how android manages memory or how bitmaps are loaded? Is there a way of solving this?

**Notes**:

Running on Android 5.1.1 (using ART rather than Dalvik VM on Android 4) does not run into this error. (Running on the resurrection remix mod on the same model of device).

Comment: what's the size of your PNGs ?

Comment: Yes, obviously...  Bitmap - depends on color information - takes pixelSize *width *height....  For argb8888 pixelSize = 4

Answer (score 0):

Per app memory limits can be as low as 16 megabytes currently.  If you have several large bitmaps it is easy to exceed this limit.

I recommend to loading a scaled down / subsampled version of each bitmap as described here: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

More info on working with bitmaps efficiently in Android here: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Another option you could try is to use the Android Asset Studio Nine-Patch generator (https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html), which will likely reduce your images to the correct resolution for each device.  Most likely your current images are higher resolution than is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

PNG is a compressed format and reading the [Bitmap page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html) seems to indicate it stores uncompressed images like the bitmap file format (BMP). Try saving the PNG files as BMP files and see how much memory it would take to store it uncompressed. Depending on the bitmap format you're looking at something from height*width bytes to 4 times that.